# Does an increase in monster Toughness also mean an increase in monster trophy value?

Tags: arkham-horror

There are several things that change a monster's Toughness. For instance:

- [Azathoth](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Azathoth) gives +1 Toughness to all Maniacs for the duration of the game
- [Heat Wave](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Heat_Wave) gives +1 Toughness to all Fire Vampires while the environment is active
- [Shub-Niggurath](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Shub-Niggurath) gives *all* monsters +1 Toughness for the duration of the game

When effects like these are in play, the monster's Toughness in combat is higher than printed on the monster token. Does this also increase the monster's trophy value?

If yes, what happens in the event of temporary changes to the monster's Toughness? For instance, if a Fire Vampire was killed before a Heat Wave, is the trophy worth one extra point if a Heat Wave strikes later? And if a Fire Vampire is killed during a Heat Wave and then the environment is replaced with something else, is the trophy back to the original value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You always apply whatever toughness modifiers are in effect when you exchange the trophy, the trophy's worth when you gained it is irrelevant.

To refer to your examples, a Fire Vampire killed before a Heat Wave, and exchanged during a Heat Wave is worth +1 toughness, while a Fire Vampire killed during a Heat Wave and exchanged after the Heat Wave has ended is worth only the monster's base toughness.

From the [Arkham Horror FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/AHfaq.pdf) (page 3):

> **Q:** When spending monster trophies, do you count any 
>   modifiers to toughness currently in effect?
>
> **A:** Yes, use the modified toughness. This bonus applies to 
>   the use of any monster trophies spent at any location.